# Modify Pandas Dataframe columns based on latest columns

Tags: python, pandas

My `pandas.DataFrame` looks like this :

```
runseq  custid  m6    m7
 1       123    x     y
 1       345    y     z
 1       213    a     b
 2       123    a     c
 2       345    z     w
 2       213    x     k
 3       123    m     n
 3       345    o     p
 3       213    a     b
```

I want all of the previous `runseq` (1,2) `m6` and `m7` values to be replaced by latest `runseq` (3). Like this:

```
runseq  custid  m6    m7
 1       123    m     n
 1       345    o     p
 1       213    a     b
 2       123    m     n
 2       345    o     p
 2       213    a     b
 3       123    m     n
 3       345    o     p
 3       213    a     b
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Will you always have the same custid values for each runseq?  If so then this is kindof a trivial question in that there is a lot of duplicated data in the answer and there are multiple ways to accomplish that.

Comment: Yes the custid values are same across all runseq.

Comment: In that case, the simplest approach is just to drop all rows except runseq=3 and then merge back with the original data

Comment: Got it.So i will create dataframe for only latest `runseq`. Then will marge 2 dataframes with respective `runseq` and `custid` but `m6` and `m7` will stay same. Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for reshape, then [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for `NaNs` if no last row  with [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) (`method='bfill'`) and last [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape back:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='runseq',columns='custid')
mask = pd.Series((df1.index == df['runseq'].iat[-1]), index=df1.index)
#if necessary add ffill for forward filling NaNs
#df1 =  df1.where(mask).bfill().ffill().stack().reset_index()
df1 =  df1.where(mask).bfill().stack().reset_index()
print (df1)
0       1     123  m  n
1       1     213  a  b
2       1     345  o  p
3       2     123  m  n
4       2     213  a  b
5       2     345  o  p
6       3     123  m  n
7       3     213  a  b
8       3     345  o  p
```

Another solution:

You can use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeating transposing values:

```
#columns for repaet
cols = ['m6','m7']
#get last value of column runseq
print (df['runseq'].iat[-1])
3

#create df1 with last group by filtering by boolean indexing
df1 = df.loc[df['runseq'] == df['runseq'].iat[-1], cols]
print (df1)
  m6 m7
6  m  n
7  o  p
8  a  b

#repeat values 3 times (length of groups by runseq) and assign back to columns
df[cols] = np.tile(df1.T.values, len(df['runseq'].unique())).transpose()
print (df)
   runseq  custid m6 m7
0       1     123  m  n
1       1     345  o  p
2       1     213  a  b
3       2     123  m  n
4       2     345  o  p
5       2     213  a  b
6       3     123  m  n
7       3     345  o  p
8       3     213  a  b
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [`pandas.DataFrame.update()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

#### Code:

```
new_values = df[df.runseq == 3][['custid', 'm6', 'm7']].set_index('custid')
df = df.set_index('custid')
df.update(new_values)
df = df.reset_index()
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    runseq  custid  m6    m7
     1       123    x     y
     1       345    y     z
     1       213    a     b
     2       123    a     c
     2       345    z     w
     2       213    x     k
     3       123    m     n
     3       345    o     p
     3       213    a     b"""), header=1)

new_values = df[df.runseq == 3][['custid', 'm6', 'm7']].set_index('custid')
df = df.set_index('custid')
df.update(new_values)
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
   custid  runseq m6 m7
0     123       1  m  n
1     345       1  o  p
2     213       1  a  b
3     123       2  m  n
4     345       2  o  p
5     213       2  a  b
6     123       3  m  n
7     345       3  o  p
8     213       3  a  b
```